# Matrix - using Limit on block types

Tags: matrix, block-types, limit

I'm using Matrix fields for blog posts. These are made up of text and image block types. I want to pull in only the first image block and a snippet of text from the first text block into the blogs index page for listing the entries.

Adding limit(1) to each block type didn't work.

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('blog').limit(3).find() %}
<div class="col-8  {% if loop.last %}last{% endif %}">

    {% for block in entry.blogBody %}

    {% switch block.type %}

      {% case "text" %}
      {{ block.text|hacksaw(chars='100', append='...') }}

      {% case "blogimage" %}
       {% for asset in block.image %}
          <img src="{{ asset.getUrl() }}" alt=""/>
      {% endfor %}

 {% endswitch %}

{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can limit which blocks you want by type and only show the first of each, if they exist. Something like this might do the trick:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('blog').limit(3).find() %}
    <div class="col-8  {% if loop.last %}last{% endif %}">

        {% set textBlock = entry.blogBody.type('text').first() %}
        {% set imgBlock = entry.blogBody.type('blogimage').first() %}

        {% if textBlock %}
            {{ textBlock.text|hacksaw(chars='100', append='...') }}
        {% endif %}

        {% if imgBlock %}
              <img src="{{ imgBlock.image[0].getUrl() }}" alt=""/>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get a Recoverable error : Object of class Craft\ElementCriteriaModel could not be converted to string error for this

Comment: @sarah3585 just made an edit - forgot to add `.text` to your textBlock matrix block. I also changed `.limit(1)` to `.first()`. Let me know if that works!